# How to disable cell after click

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell

I need to disable the click of a cell after the user has clicked on it. 
Let me explain:
I click on the cell n.3 in the table, and after this should no longer be clickable. 
You can do this?
I make this code for obtain the cell:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
{
trs[i].onclick = clickHandler;
console.log([i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a javascript programmer, but i'll try to answer:

Your code just initializes the onclick event over all your 'td' elements to use clickHandler.

Every event handler admits an event, which has a reference to the object subject of that event inside. So if you implement clickHandler like this:

```
// Add event to your clickHandler prototype if not already present
funcion clickHandler(event) {
    // Your existing code
    event = event || window.event; // window.event used in IE<9
    event.target.onclick = null; // event.target is the element clicked (myself!)
}
```

This way your clickHandler will deactivate the onclick event on the target once called, which seems what you asked for. I've not tried this, but may work or give you the idea.

**EDIT**: Full example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="javascript">
function clickHandler(event) {
    window.alert("You clicked on an unclicked cell!");
    event = event || window.event;
    event.target.onclick = null;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
    {
        trs[i].onclick = clickHandler;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it does work; try better. I've edited the answer with a full working example. Not very elegant, i'm not a web programmer.

Comment: Yeah. It function :) thanks. Can you explain how to run the check if the cell has already been clicked?

Comment: If a cell has already been clicked its onclick event is null. You can check it that way. Do you mean this? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: Ok I get it. His solution works, the problem is that I can not implement it in this code: http://jsfiddle.net/qLZLw/
could you give me more help? Thank you because it helped me so much :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want... Stop and unregister onclick event after key found? just that?

Comment: Yes, I want this! :) 
When the key is found, the clicks stop. 
When the user clicks on a box that has already been pressed, the attempts do not decrease. 
Sorry if I have not explained well, but my English is not very good.

Comment: I've forked your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cHTy . I think this is what you want. Play and work a bit more before asking!